# Keep the list view selected items ticked all the time

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, mobile-development

In my app Ive got details about movies from the user and saved them in a sqlite database , from this database ive created listview which displays the names of the movies with checkboxes where the user can check to mark the movie as one of his/her favorites.

Ive got a separate column to store if a movie is a favorite or not.... initially ive declared all the movies as "not favorites" so when the user checks the checkbox and press the button "mark as favorites" the value of the column favorites corresponding to that movie updates from "not favorites" to "favorites"

what I want to do is , keep the user selected movies checked all the time in the checkbox even after a restart of the application. As in the state should not be changed.

Code to create the list view

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DataBaseHelper myDb;
ListView movieNList;
Button addFavoritesB,button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    movieNList =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.moviesLV);
    myDb=new DataBaseHelper(this);
    addFavoritesB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    ArrayList<String> theList=new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data=myDb.getData();

    if (data.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,"The Database is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{

        //Adds data to the list view
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            Collections.sort(theList);
            ListAdapter listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,theList);
            movieNList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }

    buttonAction();
    viewAll();
}
```

XML code

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/moviesLV"
    android:layout_width="412dp"
    android:layout_height="414dp"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    android:listSelector="@color/teal_200"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

</ListView>
```

Also is there a way to change the checkbox icon from a tick to a star ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Recycler view with custom adapter**. You can update the checked/Star imageview based on the **Favourite column** value.

Here is a an exaple of custom adapter for recycler view:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<String> mMovies;

public MoviesAdapter(ArrayList<String> movies) {
    mMovies = movies;
}

@Override
public MoviesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mName.setText(mMovies.get(position));
    if (COLUMN_FAVURITE) ?
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.star) 
        : holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkBox);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMovies.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mName;
    public ImageView mFavourite;
    

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mFavourite = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favourite);

    }
}
```

}